# How to call a function that is in a js file from another js file

Tags: javascript, external

I know this question has been answered many times but the solutions in those questions aren't working for me. I have a function in lets suppose, a.js. This function is outside the document.ready function and here is its format:

```
function thisIsFromAnotherFile(){
    alert("This alert is from another js file");
}
```

I'm calling this function from the other file, b.js this way:

```
var openFile = function(context){
    thisIsFromAnotherFile();
}
```

openFile is an onclick function.

```
onclick = "openFile(this)"
```

When I run this code I'm getting an 
**Uncaught ReferenceError: thisIsFromAnotherFile is not defined**. Please help me out. Thanks.

Comment: how you load you .js files in, are you using any front-end modularization tool like `requirejs` or `browserify` or `webpack`?

Comment: You have to include the file containing `thisIsfromAnotherFile` using a `<script>` tag.

Comment: I don't know which front-end modularization tool, Im working on someone else's code.

Comment: I have two html files. I have to include 'thisIsfromAnotherFile' to the 'b.html' ?

Comment: This is what I have to include, right?

'<script type="text/javascript"> thisIsFromAnotherFile </script>'

Comment: could you also attach your html files?

Comment: nope, you need to load by `<script type="text/javascript" src='path/to/a.js'> </script>`

Comment: @elaijuh I can't. The html files are of over 500+ lines. Anything specific I should look for?

Comment: look at <head> tag and include the <script> in, just refer to my answer

Comment: @elaijuh this didn't work too. I added this line (with the correct path) in the html file of b.html (where I called the function)
`<script type="text/javascript" src='path/to/a.js'> </script>`

Comment: have you included b.js as well?

Comment: it's better to attach the part of b.html where you load all your js and which element you put `onclick` on

Answer (score -1):

> A function cannot be called unless it was defined in the same file or one loaded before the attempt to call it.
>   You declare function fn1 in File1.js, and then in File2 you can just have fn1();

```
 File1.js
function thisIsFromAnotherFile() {
alert("working");
}

File2.js

 function openFile() {
 thisIsFromAnotherFile();
 }

**HTML**
<html>
<head>
<script src="File1.js" type="text/javascript"></script> 
<script src="File2.js" type="text/javascript"></script> 
</head>
 <body>
 <button onclick="openFile()">Click me</button>
 </body>
 </html>
```

Answer (score -1):

It seems likely there's a few things you're not telling us.
The following code provides a minimal, functioning example.

**file1.html**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<script>
"use strict";
window.addEventListener('load', onDocLoaded, false);

function onDocLoaded()
{
}
</script>
<script src="filea.js"></script>
<script src="fileb.js"></script>
<style>
</style>
</head>
<body>
    <button onclick='fromFileA();'>Fire func in filea.js</button>
</body>
</html>
```

**filea.js**

```
function fromFileA()
{
    fromFileB();
}
```

**fileb.js**

```
function fromFileB()
{
    alert("now in fileb.js");
}
```

Answer (score -1):

you need to load a.js before you call the function

```
<head>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="path/to/a.js"></script>
</head>
```

Comment: Didn't work. It's still giving me the reference error. I loaded it after a script loads jQuery.