# Send a parameter to a function from another JS file

Tags: javascript, jquery

I looked for my answer ([How to call a function that is in a js file from another js file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27653657/how-to-call-a-function-that-is-in-a-js-file-from-another-js-file/45842981#45842981) and other questions) but didn't help me.

This is my function and its file name is "JS & jQuery 1.js":

```
function viewProduct(id){
    if(id){
       var idNumber= id.slice(7);
       viewCurrentProduct(idNumber);
   }
}
```

And I want to send the parameter to the "JS & jQuery 2.js". They are in the same folder. This is the code from "JS & jQuery 2.js":

```
 function viewCurrentProduct(idNumber){
     if(idNumber){
        alert(idNumber);
     }
 }
```

And in my HTML file in included :

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="JS & jQuery 2.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="JS & jQuery 1.js"></script>
```

What do I miss?

Comment: Please don't put spaces and special characters in filenames you use in URLs

Comment: Could you provide what error you are getting in the console? This could be a path related issue

Comment: May be reverse the order of files 1 and 2. Are these functions defined inside self executing classes. The idea is that when viewCurrentProduct is called, it should be available on the page.

Comment: This is my error: Uncaught ReferenceError: viewCurrentProduct is not defined at viewProduct at HTMLButtonElement.onclick

Comment: I reversed the order of files 1 and 2 but still doesn't work

Answer (score 0):

There should not be any issue with the method call. It should work perfectly. Can you check your browser console if you are getting any exception for the slice method. If id parameter parameter is integer, slice will not work as it is method of string. Just change `var idNumber= id.slice(7);` to `var idNumber= id.toString().slice(7);`

Comment: I changed the code to: var idNumber= id.toString().slice(7); but still doesn't work. I have the same error.

Comment: You might be getting the error due to some other issue. Passing the parameter from one js to other is perfectly fine. Once you fix that error, It should work. Share your complete html and js.